# How to replace `created_at` field with `updated_at` field in templates when a post is updated?

Tags: python, django, datetime, model

I have the following model wherein is `created_at` and `updated_at` field respectively:

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',upload_to='posts/%Y/%m/%d')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

and this is the result when I create a post:
[image]

I want it to show only `Posted now` text, the current time, and only when I update that field it should show `Updated now` text.

and this is the html of above template:

```
<small class="text-secondary">Posted {{ object.created_at|naturaltime }}</small><br>
<small class="text-secondary">Updated {{ object.updated_at|naturaltime }}</small><br>
```

I don't know whether to change my `model` or use some `if conditions` in my template, Can you please help me do this? Thank you very much!

Comment: I think u can apply a simple check to see whether createdOn and UpdatedOn are same, if same then only show createdOn

Comment: Yes yes, it worked as expected. Thank you so much @skaul05

Answer (score 0):

If you make `updated_at` nullable and only set it when a post is updated, a null check on `updated_at` would be an easy and reliable way to determine if a post has been updated.

```
<small class="text-secondary">
    {% if object.updated_at %}
        Updated {{ object.updated_at|naturaltime }}
    {% else %}
        Posted {{ object.created_at|naturaltime }}
    {% endif %}
</small><br>
```

However, since you always have `updated_at` being set (including on creation), an equality check against `created_at` *might* work. If you attempt that, though, you should check carefully to see whether those datetimes will always end up being exactly equal. Whether that check will actually work depends on how and when exactly both of those values are being generated.

If you're not 100% sure that the datetimes will match when they should, you may need to pick a delta that's small enough to guess reasonably well whether a post has been updated.

```
def updated(self):
    return (self.updated_at - self.created_at) < timedelta(microseconds=100)
```

I think you'd be better off either nulling `updated_at` or keeping an `updated` flag on the model rather than depending on math that might not be consistent across platforms.

Comment: Thank you @kungphu, I can make `updated_at` nullable by setting `null=True` in models, but how do I set it when a post is updated?

Comment: You can just set it manually to `datetime.now()`. You have your choice of where to do that, but one easy place would be registering a [`pre_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save) signal and setting `updated_at` when the `id` value is present (meaning the model has been saved previously, so the current save operation is due to an update).